# What is the most performant way of reading a u8 byte file and parsing information from it in rust?

Tags: file, rust, byte

My question is more on the side of performance in relation to the operations I want to do.

## question

I have a `u8 byte` file where I know the byte offsets of the information I want to pull from it, and their lengths in bytes. Ideally I want to store this information in some kind of object for use afterwards.

### ex.

- Need Info1 @ byte offset `0x2C`
- Need Info2 @ byte offset `0X30`

My naive solution to this problem is to offset the `read_exact` buffer on the file im reading then get the info i want at a variable byte length (see below).

### naive solution

```rust
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut file = File::open("foo.xd")?;
    
    // read till offset
    let mut offset = [0; 0x2C];
    file.read_exact(&mut offset)?;

    // then get the byte of information i want 
    let mut info1 = [0; 0x1];
    file.read_exact(&mut info1)?;
    println!("{info1:?}");

    // do some kind of repeatable process for the other information

    Ok(())
}
```

I lack experience in rust to know whether performing this operation over and over again on different offsets is good or bad. My intuition says bad. Would someone be able to suggest a repeatable pattern here that would work for my use case, but is also valid from a performance standpoint?

Comment: If the `Seek` trait is implemented for the `File` struct you are using (`std::fs::File` implements it), you can use `file.seek(0x2C);` to skip the first `0x2C` values and then read whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

As @Kenny mentions, if you want to jump large distances in a file you probably want to use the `Seek` trait.

`data.txt`:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

`main.rs`:

```rust
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{Read, Seek, SeekFrom},
};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut file = File::open("data.txt")?;

    // Buffer to read into
    let mut buffer = [0u8; 5];

    // Read at position 10
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(10))?;
    file.read_exact(&mut buffer)?;
    println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buffer).unwrap());

    // Read at position 5
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(5))?;
    file.read_exact(&mut buffer)?;
    println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buffer).unwrap());

    Ok(())
}
```

```
"klmno"
"fghij"
```

Of course, if your data lies in ordered positions, you could use relative seeks as well:

```rust
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{Read, Seek, SeekFrom},
};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut file = File::open("data.txt")?;

    // Buffer to read into
    let mut buffer = [0u8; 5];

    // Read at position 5
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(5))?;
    file.read_exact(&mut buffer)?;
    println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buffer).unwrap());

    // Read at position 12
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Current(2))?;
    file.read_exact(&mut buffer)?;
    println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buffer).unwrap());

    Ok(())
}
```

```
"fghij"
"mnopq"
```

---

A little excurse.

You could wrap it in a function:

```rust
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{Read, Seek, SeekFrom},
};

fn read_at_position(f: &mut File, pos: u64, buffer: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    f.seek(SeekFrom::Start(pos))?;
    f.read_exact(buffer)
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut file = File::open("data.txt")?;

    // Buffer to read into
    let mut buffer = [0u8; 5];

    // Read at position 10
    read_at_position(&mut file, 10, &mut buffer)?;
    println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buffer).unwrap());

    // Read at position 5
    read_at_position(&mut file, 5, &mut buffer)?;
    println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buffer).unwrap());

    Ok(())
}
```

Or even implement it as a trait for `File`:

```rust
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{Read, Seek, SeekFrom},
};

trait ReadAtPosition {
    fn read_at_position(&mut self, pos: u64, buffer: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<()>;
}

impl ReadAtPosition for File {
    fn read_at_position(&mut self, pos: u64, buffer: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        self.seek(SeekFrom::Start(pos))?;
        self.read_exact(buffer)
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut file = File::open("data.txt")?;

    // Buffer to read into
    let mut buffer = [0u8; 5];

    // Read at position 10
    file.read_at_position(10, &mut buffer)?;
    println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buffer).unwrap());

    // Read at position 5
    file.read_at_position(5, &mut buffer)?;
    println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buffer).unwrap());

    Ok(())
}
```